# GUI architecture for application with 4 modes (MFC/C++)

Tags: c++, user-interface, visual-c++, architecture, mfc

I'm developing a calculation-type application in which the user can choose to do one of 4 types of calculation (or 'modes' of the program). One of which can be entering new data, the rest can use the existing (file IO) data to do the calculations on. Each mode requires at least two 'views' of the calculation output (chart and table of results). The user should know clearly what mode they are executing and so toggle buttons on a toolbar, or status bar text isn't 'strong' enough.

I'm considering using an SDI interface, with multiple (tabbed?) views (MFC doc/view), and with a non-moveable CDockablePane hosting controls. These controls need to make it clear to the user what mode of the program they are in.

It seems a common type of application structure/pattern/design, but I'm struggling to find any similar examples. I'd love to hear any suggestions, or maybe even the formal name for the type of design problem I face.

Thanks!

I also considered a dialog-based application, which seems more appropriate given it could be tab-based. However, the chart and grid output need to be multi-window resizeable, hence the SDI basis.

Comment: Try SDI + CFornView + Tab control in CFormView.

Comment: Thanks Alex. That could be a runner. The Chart and Grid could then be implemented as controls in the CFormView. Is this better than tabbed multiple CViews and the control panel? I'm not sure.

Comment: What constraints are driving the apparent need for modes?

Comment: Basically different kinds of operations on the data.

Comment: It is simple and straightforward, and doesn't require any tricks. But if you want to make the window resizable, you need to make dynamic controls resizing - there are several wrappers for this.

Comment: Doesn't sound convincing.

Comment: Even if MFC happens to be the only GUI framework you know you will probably save yourself a lot of effort by just learning a new framework than starting a new application using MFC.

Comment: Happy to do that @sjdowling if there's a good reason. Is there a good GUI design for this type of app that can't be done or is hard with MFC? My reason for MFC is because of C++ speed for the calculations part.

Comment: @Colin There's a lot of stuff you can't do easily in MFC, such as having dynamic sizing of controls like Alex Farber mentioned, that is easy in pretty much every other GUI toolkit. The only reason people use MFC today is because they have an application that was first written in the 90s and have too much code to port to another framework even though Microsoft has abandoned MFC. An alternative would be to use a modern C++ framework like Qt or do the performance stuff in a C++ library and call that library from Java, python or C#.

Comment: @sjdowling Thanks for the extra info!It made me feel like a programming dinosaur, so I've been reading heaps about WPF/C#. One problem seems to be the difficulty calling C++ native DLLs from a WPF/C# app - P/Invoke needs lots of detailed marshalling even for basic data types. Hence it seems difficult to pass full class objects across the interface. Am I missing something on this?

Comment: No, marshaling is a price you generally have to pay whenever crossing language boundaries or even across C API and COM boundaries, whether or not it is worthwhile is really dependent on your circumstances. Can you easily narrow down the C++ code to just the performance critical parts and reduce the marshaling effort to an acceptable level or does it make more sense to pay the development cost of writing it all in C++? For the case of C#/C++ there are plenty of technologies available such as C++/CLI to make it easier. Ultimately the best course to take is going to vary depending on the project.

Comment: More reading to do :) Thanks so much for your insights!